# how to install english MUI on windows web server 2008 R2

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, web-server, language-packs

I am trying to install English MUI on Windows Web Server 2008 R2 SP1 (Russian) but I have no luck so far.

I tried to install [lp.cab from 6001.18000.080118-1840_amd64fre_Server_LP_1-KRMSLPX1_DVD.img](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=22681) and it says that file is corrupted or invalid and it suggested to change file location which I did but again - no luck.

Also I tried [Windows6.1-KB974587-x64-en-us.exe](http://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=1246) but it did nothing. I noticed that **lp.cab** file appears in folder for a little while after running exe which I managed to copy before it was removed and I tried to supply this cab file to **lpksetup.exe** and it was recognised it but said that it is not possible to install this language on this computer.

Is it possible to make russian version of Windows Web Server 2008 R2 SP1 in english without completely reisntalling it? If so please advise how.